# Using System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel create new thread in the thread pool?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, task-parallel-library

Maybe I did not understand it right ... all the Parallel class issue   :(

But from what I am reading now, I understand that when I use the Parallel I actually mobilize all the threads that exists in the threadPool for some task/mission.

**For example**:

```
  var arrayStrings = new string[1000];
  Parallel.ForEach<string>(arrayStrings, someString =>
  {
       DoSomething(someString);
  });
```

So the Parallel.ForEach in this case is mobilizing all the threads that exists in the threadPool for the 'DoSomething' task/mission.

But does the call Parallel.ForEach will create any new thread at all?

Its clear that there will be no 1000 new threads. But lets assume that there are 1000 new threads, some case that the threadPool release all the thread that it hold so, in this case ... the Parallel.ForEach will create any new thread?

Comment: [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) - "Executes a foreach (For Each in Visual Basic) operation in which iterations **may** run in parallel."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: `Parallel.ForEach()` does not “mobilize all the threads”. And any operation that schedules some work on the `ThreadPool` (which `Parallel.ForEach()` does) can cause creation of new thread in the pool.

Long answer: To understand this properly, you need to know how three levels of abstraction work: `Parallel.ForEach()`, `TaskScheduler` and `ThreadPool`:

1. `Parallel.ForEach()` (and `Parallel.For()`) schedule their work on a `TaskScheduler`. If you don't specify a scheduler explicitly, [the current one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current.aspx) will be used.

   `Parallel.ForEach()` splits the work between several `Task`s. Each `Task` will process a part of the input sequence, and when it's done, it will request another part if one is available, and so on.

   How many `Task`s will `Parallel.ForEach()` create? As many as the `TaskScheduler` will let it run. The way this is done is that each `Task` first enqueues a copy of itself when it starts executing (unless doing so would violate [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx), if you set it). This way, the actual concurrency level is up to the `TaskScheduler`.

   Also, the first `Task` will actually execute on the current thread, if the `TaskScheduler` supports it (this is done using [`RunSynchronously()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously)).
2. [The default `TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default.aspx) simply enqueues each `Task` to the `ThreadPool` queue. (Actually, it's more complicated if you start a `Task` from another `Task`, but that's not relevant here.) Other `TaskScheduler`s can do completely different things and some of them (like [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx)) are completely unsuitable for use with `Parallel.ForEach()`.
3. The `ThreadPool` uses quite a complex algorithm to decide exactly how many threads should be running at any given time. But the most important thing here is that scheduling new work item *can* cause the creating of a new thread (although not necessarily immediately). And because with `Parallel.ForEach()`, there is always some item queued to be executed, it's completely up to the internal algorithm of `ThreadPool` to decide the number of threads.

Put together, it's pretty much impossible to decide how many threads will be used by a `Parallel.ForEach()`, because it depends on many variables. Both extremes are possible: that the loop will run completely synchronously on the current thread and that each item will be run on its own, newly created thread.

But generally, is should be close to optimal efficiency and you probably don't have to worry about all those details.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel.Foreach does not create new threads, nor does it "mobilize all the threads". It uses a limited number of threads from the threadpool and submits tasks to them for parallel execution. In the current implementation the default is to use one thread per core.

Comment: That's simply not true. If the code inside `Parallel.ForEach()` blocks or runs for a long time, more threads than the number of cores will be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this the wrong way round.
From [PATTERNS OF PARALLEL PROGRAMMING](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19222) you'll see that Parallel.ForEach is just really syntactic sugar.

The Parallel.ForEach is largely boiled down to something like this,

```
for (int p = 0; p < arrayStrings.Count(); p++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoSomething(arrayStrings[p]);
}
```

The ThreadPool takes care of the scheduling.  There are some excellent articles around how the ThreadPool's scheduler behaves to some degree if you're interested, but that's nothing to do with TPL.

Comment: `new Thread()` will always create a new thread, not use one from the threadpool. The code you posted will always create as many threads as there are items in the collection. This in no way represents Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach()` is not built on top of `ThreadPool`, it's built on top of `TaskScheduler`. Also, it's smarter about the code in each `Task`, so that there isn't one `Task` per item. Another thing is that your code would not block, but `Parallel.ForEach()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel does not deal with threads at all - it schedules TASKS to the task framework. THat then has a scheduler and the default scheduler goes to the threadpool. This one will try to find a goo number of threads (better in 4.5 than 4.0) and the Threadpool may slowly spin up new threads.

But that is not a functoin of parallel.foreach ;)

> the Parallel.ForEach will create any new thread ???

It never will. As I said - it has 1000 foreach, then it queues 10.000 tasks, Point. THe Task factory scheduler will do what it is programmed to do ((you can replace it). Generally, default - yes, slowly new threads will spring up WITHIN REASON.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach()` on a collection of *n* items will generally not create *n* `Task`s, that might be too inefficient. It partitions the source collection and creates only as many `Task`s as the `TaskScheduler` allows it to run.