# How to TPL determine the number of threads to use?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I've helped a client with an application which stopped doing it's work after a while (it eventually started doing work again).

The problem was that when a `Task` failed it used `Thread.Sleep` for 5 seconds (in the task). As there could be up to 800 tasks queued every two second you can imagine the problem if many of those jobs fails and invoked `Thread.Sleep`. None of those jobs were marked with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.

I rewrote the tasks so that `Thread.Sleep` (or `Task.Delay` for that matter) wasn't nessacary.

However, I'm interested in what the `TaskScheduler` (the default) did in that scenario. How and when do it increase the number of threads?

Comment: If you could use `await Task.Delay()`, that would solve your problem.

Comment: @svick: I've fixed the problem. That's not the question

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

> Behind the scenes, tasks are queued to the ThreadPool, which has been
>   enhanced with algorithms (like hill-climbing) that determine and
>   adjust to the number of threads that maximizes throughput.

The [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) will have a maximum number of threads depending on the environment. As you create more `Task`s the pool can run them concurrently until it reaches its maximum number of threads, at which point any further tasks will be queued.

If you want to find out the maximum number of `ThreadPool` threads you can use [`System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads.aspx) (you need to pass in two out int parameters, one that will be populated with the number of maximum worker threads and another that will be populated with the maximum number of asynchronous I/O threads).

If you want to get a better idea of what is happening in your application at runtime you can use [Visual Studio's threads window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx) by going to Debug -> Windows -> Threads (The entry will only be there when you are debugging so you'll need to set a break point in your application first).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850099/using-system-threading-tasks-parallel-create-new-thread-in-the-thread-pool/10854683#10854683) is possibly of interest. It would seem the [default task scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx) simply queues the task up in the ThreadPool's queue unless you use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. This means that it's up to the `ThreadPool` to decide when to create new threads.

Comment: TPL do not use all of the thread pool threads, as that would starvate all other thread pool users. I'm interested in the default task schedulers algorithm which decide when and how new threads should be enlisted.

Comment: See edit on the default task scheduler. It uses the ThreadPool unless you use the LongRunning option. I'd highly recommend using the Threads window whilst debugging to monitor what's actually happening.

Comment: Yeah, but it do not put all tasks in different thread pool threads directly but can queue tasks too. I want to know when it decide to use the thread pool and when to queue a task instead.